# Segmentation fault (core dumped) ao acessar String

Tags: c, c++, compilação

Montei o código abaixo para separar apenas os últimos caracteres de um link (os últimos 11 para ser mais exato). Até então tudo funciona bem, os cálculos são feitos normalmente, os valores também batem. O problema é na hora de dar `printf` nos valores da String(vetor), o problema é retornado `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  char link[100];
  int linkSize, calcLink;

  scanf("%s", &link);
  //lê o tamanho da string pra capturar os últimos caracteres
  linkSize = strlen(link);

  printf("\nTamanho da String: %i\n", linkSize);

  calcLink = linkSize - 11;

  printf("%s\n", link);

  int i = calcLink;
  while(i < linkSize){
    printf("%s\n", link[i]);
    ++i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Como conseguir acessar os últimos endereços de memória da minha String `link` e como guardar em outra string esses últimos caracteres. Espero ter sido claro. Sei que é algo bem básico mas por mais que eu tenha procurado não consegui achar uma resposta que pudesse solucionar esse caso em específico. Desde já agradeço vossa compreensão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem algumas coisas que precisa de acertar:

- Quando faz `printf` com `%s` é suposto passar um ponteiro como parametro, que foi algo que faltou em:

  ```
  printf("%s\n", link[i]);
  ```

  Uma vez que está a passar um carater o formatador mais indicado seria `%c`.
- Em `scanf("%s", &link);` tem um `&` a mais pois o `scanf` tem de receber o endereço de memoria onde vai colocar os dados lidos e `link` por ser um ponteiro já refere um endereço de memória.
- Faltou incluir `<string.h>` que é de onde vem a função `strlen`

Mas se apenas pretende mostrar o resultado pode simplesmente fazer `printf` `%s` passando o endereço base que é `link` e somando `X` posições de memoria até chegar aos últimos `11`, não sendo assim necessário um loop:

```
linkSize = strlen(link);
printf("\nTamanho da String: %i\n", linkSize);

calcLink = linkSize - 11;
if (calcLink < 0) calcLink = 0; //nao deixar a posição ser negativa

//aqui soma ao ponteiro link as posições de memoria necessárias para chegar aos ultimos 11
printf("%s\n", link + calcLink);
```

[Exemplo deste código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/3cYYH4)

Se pretender construir uma nova string com este texto basta alocar de forma estática ou dinâmica e copiar os carateres tanto manualmente como com [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void last_link(char* link, int char_count, char* last_chars){
    int linkSize = strlen(link);
    int calcLink = linkSize - char_count;
    if (calcLink < 0) calcLink = 0;

    memcpy(last_chars, link + calcLink, char_count); //copiar os carateres
    last_chars[char_count] = '\0'; //colocar o terminador
}

int main() {
    char link[100];

    scanf("%s", link);
    printf("\nTamanho da String: %i\n", strlen(link));

    char last_chars[12]; //tem de ter mais 1 caractere para o terminador \0
    last_link(link, 11, last_chars); //obter os últimos 11

    printf("%s\n", last_chars);

    return 0;
}
```

[Exemplo também deste código no Ideone](https://ideone.com/vEFAqp)

Podia ter feito a criação da nova `string` diretamente dentro da função `last_link` com `malloc` mas isso iria implicar a quem chamasse a função de não se poder esquecer de fazer `free` caso contrário teria uma fuga de memória.

Comment: Interessante. Cada vez que exploro este fórum fico mais surpreso com o tanto de conhecimento podemos adquirir aqui. É bom ver que pessoas experientes estão dispostas à ajudar neófitos como eu. Agradeço pela sua resposta, foi de grande ajuda, nunca entendi muito bem o funcionamento de ponteiros, na verdade nunca nem me importei muito. Vejo que isso afeta diretamente o desenvolvimento de um programa. Agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: @HenriqueMarques Fico contente de ter ajudado. Quando se programa em C, a menos que sejam coisas muito simples é comum termos de lidar com ponteiros, e por isso é importante de saber trabalhar com eles.